# does gradle 4.3 fix issue on play 2.6.6 and scala 2.12?

Tags: scala, gradle, playframework

does anyone know if gradle 4.3 fix the issue on play 2.6.6 and scala 2.12? It does not say in https://docs.gradle.org/current/release-notes.html

I wonder if this PR is not approved yet?https://github.com/gradle/gradle/pull/3018

Answer (score 0):

I work with the author of that PR. From what I understand, Gradle will not work with Play 2.6 until that PR is merged. As of now (6 Nov 2017) it is still waiting to be merged.

https://github.com/gradle/gradle/pull/3018

You may wish to add a  reaction to the PR to show your support. :)

Comment: It looks like the PR is merged, but does not say in release note https://docs.gradle.org/4.3.1/release-notes.html that Play 2.6 is supported. can you please help confirm? thanks

Comment: I think it's in that release, but not 100% sure. Try it out and let us know!